# Why after replace Fragment,ViewPager that in this fragment doesn't create its child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My Application's structure is:

A `MainActivity` have 5 tabs(`ImageView` + `TextView`), main part is a `FrameLayout` that switch 5 `Fragment`s.

In first `Fragment`(named `ScheduleFragment`), it's function is to query school schedule(meaning have 7 page to show a whole week's schedule). So I use a `ViewPager` to show the schedule.

`ViewPager` is using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

First at all, I start my app,and input something to query schedule, onClick ---> Thread.start() ---> sendMessage(Message) ---> handler.handleMessage() ---> updateUI().

My `ViewPager` show the result schedule successful.

While I click tab to switch Fragment(`ScheduleFragment` change to `OtherFragment`), and switch back(return to the `ScheduleFragment`).The ViewPager in `ScheduleFragment` doesn't show data.

I print some lifecycle method to check out what happened.

when I get schedule data successful, I switch `ViewPager`'s page. ViewPager's each fragment page will invoke `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`.

when I click tab to swich other MAIN fragment and return `ScheduleFragment`. ScheduleFragment's `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` be invoked, but nothing happened on  ViewPager's each fragment page.

nothing show in `ViewPager`, but when I switch `2nd` ViewPager's fragment, `Logcat` print 3nd fragment's `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
//this method in ScheduleFragment.java  
private void updateSchedule(WeekSchedule ws) {
    Log.i(TAG, "updateSchedule - ws" + ws.toString());

    this.scheduleHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.scheduleViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    SchedulePagerAdapter schedulePagerAdapter = new SchedulePagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), ws);
    //schedulePagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    this.scheduleViewPager.setAdapter(schedulePagerAdapter);
}
```

This is OneDayScheduleFragment.java

```
//this is fragment in ViewPager, it for each day of week schedule.
public class OneDayScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

private final String TAG = "OneDayScheduleFragment";

private WeekSchedule ws;
private int weekDay;

public WeekSchedule getWs() {
    return ws;
}

public void setWs(WeekSchedule ws) {
    this.ws = ws;
}

public int getWeekDay() {
    return weekDay;
}

public void setWeekDay(int weekDay) {
    this.weekDay = weekDay;
}

public static OneDayScheduleFragment newInstance(int index, WeekSchedule ws) {
    OneDayScheduleFragment f = new OneDayScheduleFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("weekSchedule", ws);
    b.putInt("weekDay", index);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate - " + weekDay);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView - " + weekDay);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weekschedule, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.schedule_result_listview);
    TextView textView = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.schedule_result_textview);

    int index = this.weekDay;
    WeekSchedule ws = this.ws;

    TodaySchedule ts = ws.todayScheduleArray.get(index - 1);
    int courseCount = ts.courseList.size();

    if (courseCount == 0) {
        //set header
        ...

    } else {
        //set header
        ...

        ScheduleListViewAdapter scheduleListViewAdapter = new ScheduleListViewAdapter(getActivity(), ws.todayScheduleArray.get(index - 1));
        scheduleListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(scheduleListViewAdapter);
    }

    return root;
}
}
```

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: @Luksprog Can you give me more guide?

Comment: The fragments used in the `ViewPager` from the `ScheduleFragment`(`OneDayScheduleFragment` I presume) are nested fragments so you need to use the `FragmentManager` associated with  `ScheduleFragment` which is the one returned by `getChildFragmentManager()` and not `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. So pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to the `ViewPager`'s adapter.